# Overdue task email notifications out of the box?

Tags: email, designer-workflow, tasks

I've created a simple SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow that starts the approval process on a document library. It assigns workflow tasks to users just fine and e-mails the initiator when the workflow has started/completed and when tasks are created for the approvers.

I read that out of the box, SharePoint will automatically e-mail the task recipients if their task is overdue, but I have not seen this behavior. I've tried manually starting the "Notification Timer Job" to force the overdue emails, but none were sent. Is that the timer job that is responsible for sending notifications for overdue tasks?

Also, how can I manually force the overdue task emails to send on my dev machine to test and demo to users?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an 'out of the box' feature in SharePoint to send out overdue task emails.

This question over on StackOverflow details several ways to get this done including open source projects, workflow, custom coding and commercial products *(disclaimer, one of them is from my own company).*

[SO - Dated reminders in sharepoint calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)